# Spring @Autowired messageSource working in Controller but not in other classes?

Tags: java, spring, annotations

New updates:
Dec 31 2010 8:15 PM
Very dirty fix but this is how I have temporarily made the messageSource to work. I changed my Controller class to pass the 'messageSource' to Message class and am able to retrieve the messages. Please review the class definition below and let me know any more info that you may need to help. I really appreciate all the help you are providing.

Dec 31 2010 3 PM
As I could not succeed in configuring messageSource through annotations, I attempted to configure messageSource injection through servlet-context.xml. I still have messageSource as null. Please let me know if you need any more specific info, and I will provide. Thanks for your help in advance.

```
servlet-context.xml
<beans:bean id="message"
    class="com.mycompany.myapp.domain.common.message.Message">
    <beans:property name="messageSource" ref="messageSource" />
</beans:bean>
```

Spring gives the below information message about spring initialization.

```
INFO : org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner - JSR-330 'javax.inject.Named' annotation found and supported for component scanning

INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Overriding bean definition for bean 'message': replacing [Generic bean: class [com.mycompany.myapp.domain.common.message.Message]; scope=singleton; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null; defined in file [C:\springsource\tc-server-developer-2.1.0.RELEASE\spring-insight-instance\wtpwebapps\myapp\WEB-INF\classes\com\mycompany\myapp\domain\common\message\Message.class]] with [Generic bean: class [com.mycompany.myapp.domain.common.message.Message]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null; defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml]]

INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor - JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring

INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@1c7caac5: defining beans [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping#0,org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean#0,org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.MappedInterceptor#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.HttpRequestHandlerAdapter,org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping#0,xxxDao,message,xxxService,jsonDateSerializer,xxxController,homeController,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,tilesViewResolver,tilesConfigurer,messageSource,org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.MappedInterceptor#1,localeResolver,org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver#0,validator,resourceBundleLocator,messageInterpolator]; parent: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@4f47af3
```

---

---

I have the below definition for message source in 3 classes. In debug mode, I can see that in class `xxxController`, `messageSource` is initialized to `org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource`. I have annotated Message class with @Component and xxxHibernateDaoImpl with @Repository. I also included context namespace definition in servlet-context.xml. But in `Message` class and `xxxHibernateDaoImpl` class, the `messageSource` is still null.

Why is Spring not initializing messageSource in the two other classes though in `xxxController` classes, it initializes correctly?

```
@Controller
public class xxxController{
    @Autowired
    private ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource;
}

@Component
public class Message{
 @Autowired
 private ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource;
}

@Repository("xxxDao")
public class xxxHibernateDaoImpl{
 @Autowired
 private ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource;
}

<beans:beans
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

<beans:bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
            <beans:property name="basename" value="/resources/messages/messages" />
</beans:bean>   

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.mycompany.myapp"/>
</beans>
```

Comment: How have you declared those classes to Spring?

Comment: Yes. I have declared those classes to spring. Please see updated definition above.

Answer (score 4):

Spring does not know about those classes that you are getting a null value field from.  You can tell Spring about them by defining them as beans in your app context or annotating the classes as `@Component`

The reason why your first class is getting autowired correctly is because that class is correctly annotated as `@Controller`

Comment: Please see updated classes with @Repository/@Component annotations and the servlet-context.xml. The messageSource is still null. I suspected it may be the order of definition in servlet-context.xml. Hence, I placed component scan tag after messageSource definition. Still the issue is not resolved. I see that the xxxDao and xxxController come first in instantiating debug message before messageSource (pasted below). Not sure whether that is anyway related.

Comment: INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@5883914b: defining beans [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping#0,...,xxxDao,message,xxxService,jsonDateSerializer,xxxController,homeController,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,...0,validator,resourceBundleLocator,messageInterpolator]; parent: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@3f5ebf57

Comment: INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@5883914b: defining beans [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping#0,..., xxxDao,message,xxxService,jsonDateSerializer,xxxController,homeController, ..., tilesConfigurer,messageSource,org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.MappedInterceptor#1,..., validator,resourceBundleLocator,messageInterpolator]; parent: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@3f5

Comment: @Jayaprakash: Please don't put that sort of information into comments; it's better off edited into your question. (Moreover, it triggers an “issue” in how SO formats comments, making them much harder to read.)

Comment: Sorry, about that. I did not realize the formatting issue. Later when I attempted to edit it, the other overlapping links came in. I will take care in future.

Answer (score 2):

Try to refine your base-package. Don't let spring scan all your application class com.mycompany.myapp , (you will have a better startup time).

Suppose you have your controller class in a package :  com.mycompany.myapp.controller
and your service class (annotated with @component, @repository) in package com.mycompany.myapp.services

Add this to your [servlet-name]-servlet.xml (Dispatcher context file)

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.mycompany.myapp.controller" />
```

In the other hand, open your servlet-context.xml (Supposed to be an application context loaded by contextloaderlistener) and add this :

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.mycompany.myapp.services" />
```

followed by the declaration of your messageSource as you did.

You will have one messageSource injected every where it is autowired. It should work because stuff defined in Dispatcher-context-file can see other beans declared in application-context file(s) but not the opposite

Comment: Thanks for responding to this thread. I defined component-scan first followed by messageSource definition in servlet-context.xml. Do you think I should reverse the order to ensure Spring has messageSource available while scanning components? Does it mean component scan should be done at the end, when all other beans have been defined in servlet-context.xml? Thanks for your help in advance

Comment: I tried moving component-scan at the end after messageSource definition in servlet-context.xml. But it still did not solve the problem :(

Comment: Try to be more specific about what you give to component-scan. I have updated my answer.