# Injected MessageSource is null

Tags: java, spring

**Framework: Spring 3.**

I really can't understand why the message source injectend in a bean ends up always to be NULL.

Here's the snippets:

the `servlet.xml`

```
<context:annotation-config />

<context:component-scan base-package="com.myproject.controllers" />

<mvc:annotation-driven />


<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename" value="/WEB-INF/messages/messages" />
    <property name="cacheSeconds" value="0" />
</bean>
```

the class where the messageSource is injected

```
import com.myproject.controllers.forms.RegistrationForm;

@Component
public class RegistrationFormValidator implements Validator {

@Autowired
@Qualifier("messageSource")
private MessageSource messageSource;


    //other stuff here...

}
```

here's the controller

```
@Controller
@SessionAttributes("userSearchForm")
public class UsersController extends PaginationController<ProfiledUser>{


@InitBinder(value="registrationForm")
public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder)
{
    binder.setValidator(new RegistrationFormValidator());
}
```

I have already tried the following:

1. deleting the annotations and injecting the message source via xml configuration file
2. implementing the MessageSourceAware interface
3. trying to inject a `ReloadableresourceBundleMessageSource` instead of using interface `MessageSource`

everything ends up in a epic fail ;-)
How can I get the MessageSource properly injected?

Comment: may be related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4567512/spring-autowired-messagesource-working-in-controller-but-not-in-other-classes?rq=1

Comment: Do you have an other `component-scan` in an other spring context?

Comment: @Ralph - yes, I do. I have two component-scan in a separate context file but they don't conflict, as far as I know.

Comment: How do you know that it's really null? @Autowired requires the field to be populated - does Spring print the exception stack trace during initialization which includes `org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Injection of autowired dependencies failed for class`? How is your **Validator** instance created, with the `new` operator?

Comment: @Boris Treukhov - no, the exception isn't thrown. While debugging I can see that the messageSource attribute for the class RegistrationFormValidator is simply null. I argue the injection went wrong because I can use the messageSource declared in the servlet.xml file elsewhere. For example while resolving error messages in different forms. I know spring does it automatically, so I can't be sure about the rationale laying behind the courtains.

Comment: Copy the field value to the local variable and check that it's really null.

Comment: If you have two comonent scanns than really really make sure that the other component scann (in the the other context) do not instanciate this class!

Comment: If Spring can't autowire something(either there is no bean, or there more than one beans) it always prints a specific exeption, so either autowiring is not used at all, or your null pointer exception comes from another place. Maybe you didn't put `<context:annotation-config />` in your servlet.xml.

Comment: @Ralph - Maybe I missed something but I'm pretty sure that the others compnent-scans don't instantiate the class. Just to mention, the MessageSource is declared in the servlet.xml file only and so I think the component-scan doesn't affect it.

Comment: @BorisTreukhov - thank you for your tip. Unfortunately, i have the <context:annotation-config /> declared in the servlet.xml. I updated my question to show more of my configuration file.

Comment: @maVVamaldo how is the Validator instance created? If it's done with Spring  then may be your Validator is in the root web app context - try putting <context:annotation-config /> to the root app context too

Comment: - ..eh but this will give bean not found exception because message source is not accessible from the root web app context as it resides in the dispatcher servlet context if I guess correctly

Comment: @BorisTreukhov - I have <context:annotation-config /> in each and every configuration file. I mean the context.xml file and the servlet.xml file. I have security.xml as well but of course this isn't critical here. It still doesn't work :(

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20033/discussion-between-boris-treukhov-and-mavvamaldo)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>I think that you are examining the field values of a CGLIB class</strike>

See [spring singleton bean fields are not populated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11580911/spring-singleton-bean-fields-are-not-populated)

**update**

### A general note about autowiring

`@Autowired` annotation is processed by `AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor` which can be registered by specifying `<context:annotation-config />` annotation in the respective spring configuration file(bean postprocessors work on a per container basis so you need to have different postprocessors for the servlet and for the application root context => you need to put `<context:annotation-config />` both to the web app context and the dispatcher servlet configuration ).

Please note that `@Autowired` annotation has `required` property which is set as default to true, that means that if the autowiring process occurs Spring will check that exactly one instance of the specified bean exists. If the bean which fields are annotated with `@Autowired` is a singleton then, the check will be performed during the application initialization.

**update** In this specific question the `Validator` instance was not created by Spring at all, that is why no autowiring  was performed and no initialization exceptions were thrown.

Answer (score 0):

change basename to something like this:

```
<property name="basename" value="classpath:messages/messages" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue when I tried to use the MessageSource in a custom Date Formatter.

The code AppDateFormatter

```
public class AppDateFormatter implements Formatter<Date> {

    @Autowired
    private MessageSource messageSource;

    other stuff.....

    private SimpleDateFormat createDateFormat(final Locale locale) {
        final String format = this.messageSource.getMessage("date.format", null, locale);
        final SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(format);
        dateFormat.setLenient(false);
       return dateFormat;
   }

}
```

This is what worked for me :

```
public class WebMvcConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

  other stuff.....

    @Bean
    public MessageSource messageSource() {
        ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
        messageSource.setBasenames("Messages/Messages", "Messages/Labels");
        messageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
        messageSource.setCacheSeconds(1);
        return messageSource;
    }    

    @Bean
    public AppDateFormatter appDateFormatter(){
        return new AppDateFormatter();
    }

    @Bean
    public FormattingConversionService mvcConversionService() {
        FormattingConversionService conversionService = new DefaultFormattingConversionService();
        conversionService.addFormatter(appDateFormatter()); 
        return conversionService;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the java configs class add the following beans.

```
@Bean
public MessageSource messageSource() {
    ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
    messageSource.setBasename("messages");

    return messageSource;
}

@Bean
public LocaleResolver localeResolver() {
    SessionLocaleResolver resolver = new SessionLocaleResolver();
    resolver.setDefaultLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);

    return resolver;
}

@Bean
public MessageSourceAccessor messageSourceAccessor(MessageSource messageSource){
    return new MessageSourceAccessor(messageSource, Locale.ENGLISH );
}
```

Then the `MessageSourceAccessor` bean can be injected as follows

```
@Autowired
private MessageSourceAccessor msgs;
```

Get message strings as follows,

```
msgs.getMessage("controller.admin.save.success")
```

The `message_en.properties` file should be inside `/src/main/resources` folder. Add necessary properties file for other languages as well.

Hope this helps.